# ASP.Net 4.5 logout/login fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, owin, logout

I am building a ASP.NET 4.5 application (not MVC another big story) using the .Net authentication an up to date Visual Studio 13. Yesterday I did some package manager updates that included some microsoft authentication updates. Everything was fine for a while.  Later in the day I suddenly could not log out, no errors. Searched the web for solutions and found nothing. This morning it was working fine and then late this afternoon log off stopped working again. In Chrome, which auto logs in the last user, log out will not work.  In IE, which does not auto log in, login/logout worked (after Chrome stopped working) for a while but suddenly login stopped working. I have tried closing IE, reboot my computer - no luck.  Being a programmer this kind of work/doesn't behaviour is disturbing.

My Logout code is in a logout page
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
            Session.Abandon();

```
        //Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        //FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        //HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        //Session.Abandon();
        //Roles.DeleteCookie();

        //FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        //Session.Clear();
        //Session.RemoveAll();
        //Session.Abandon();

        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", true);
    }
```

I left in the comments to show all the different things I tried. The uncommented one works fine when logout is working, like in IE when I could login.

I will get this error in Chrome when it fails, and I get it 4 times time it happens. I have my doubts it is related.

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
```

at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.Set(String name, String value)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.set_Item(String key, String[] value)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.SetHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary.AppendValues(String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.d__f.MoveNext()

I do not have a redirect in a try/catch statement anywhere in my code. I fix for most with this problem.

This is my startup which is just the default one pretty much.

```
    public partial class Startup {


    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301883
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            //ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(14, 0, 0, 0),
            SlidingExpiration = false,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
                    OnException = context => { 
                        Debug.Log(this, "CookieAuthenticationProvider exception: \n" + context.Exception.ToString());
                    }
            }
        });

        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
      app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    }
```

SlidingExpiration was True and I tried False to see it would help because of a comment somewhere, it didn't help. This is all quite mysterious with no exceptions on the login/logout failures. I wonder that it might be cookie related.

At this point I wonder if I can trust Owin if it can pull this kind of mysterious failure out the blue - I was working on completely unrelated forms in  when it failed - it works/it doesn't. Authentication must work for me to develop let alone release the product. Any suggestions for an alternate authentication  system are welcome, I suppose I could write my own simpler one but I lack time for that (at least I could debug it).

George

Comment: I removed the OnException to  try and go back closer to the default project and it all worked fine for 5 hours and then stopped again. Chrome is stuck with a user that cannot logout, IE who does not remember users cannot logon at all.  This is all so friggin strange.  The package manager does not allow me to back out of the changes.

The HttpHeaderCollection exceptions were caused by the OnException in the Startup, even though it only writes some text to a file, no redirect. So no the login/logout failure is completely silent, no exceptions.

Comment: After I logged this problem the next day all was working fine for about 5 hours of development and then on Chrome I could not log out and on IE I could not login.  I restarted Visual Studio and it worked again until I stopped working which was not long. Today it failed and will not work with restart or reboot.


My best hope is someone elses insight or an update from Microsoft to fix it. At this point I believe the problem came from Microsoft in the owin project update I did. It started happening a couple hours after the update.

Comment: I have a minimal Test project.  I created a user with the same email and password in the test project. After a test, back in my project the user changed to the login from the test project. Logout now works again (for a while).

Perhaps the problem is cookie related.  Could be all the restarting I do in development using the same user over and over is causing the cookie to have a problem that then prevents logging out somehow.

Comment: Starting the project opens a web page  and auto logs into the last user and log out falil.  If I go to another project logging into a user the user that does not exist I believe cookie get removed. If I log into a user that exists on my main project then that user will auto login and logout will work for a while.   I have done a test with logout working, of logging in and out 50 times with no problem.  After I stopped the project and restarted it, it auto logged in with logout now failing. When logout is working using asp:LoginStatus html never does, only the asp logout does.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

protected void Unnamed_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    Session.Abandon();
}
```

clear the cookies name `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`

Comment: I believe this solution has solved my logout problems.  Sorry but cannot vote it up as would like to, I do not have enough points yet.  This also got me to back to use Unamed_LoggingOut with asp:LoginStatus and I figured it that that was failing because my default page had an empty url which causes it to fail. I now have a default url instead of nothing.  Strangely the asp.net default is the no url. All good so far, thanks for the solution!